# How to create a dynamic array of objects polymorphically?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, polymorphism, dynamic-arrays

How can I create a dynamic array of objects polymorphically, if I have an abstract class with derived classes, and without using STL data structure classes? (vectors, list, etc)

**A static array of objects**

```
TwoDimensionShape *shapes[2];       
shapes[0] = &Triangle("right", 8.0, 12.0);  
shapes[1] = &Rectangle(10);
```

I know I can't do this because you cannot create objects of an abstract class:

```
cin >> x;
TwoDimensionShape *s = new TwoDimensionShape [x];
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to Nick, this works:

```
  int x = 5;
  TwoDimensionShape **shapes = new (TwoDimensionShape*[x]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an array of pointers to that class:

```
TwoDimensionShape **s = new TwoDimensionShape*[x];
```

And then construct each object with it's specific type:

```
s[0] = new Triangle("right", 8.0, 12.0);  
s[1] = new Rectangle(10);
```

Similar to what you had.
Remember to delete when you don't need anymore.

Comment: I have a problem,   int x = 5;
  TwoDimensionShape **shapes = new (TwoDimensionShape *)[x]; The compiler says "A value of type TwoDimensionShape * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type TwoDimensionShape **

Comment: You are missing an asterisk on shapes and one afer TwoDimensionShape: `TwoDimensionShape **shapes = new (TwoDimensionShape*)[x];`

Comment: Huh, that's weird, when I clicked to edit and it was in there, but nonetheless it still gives an error

Comment: Can you update the question on the top to see how the code is after this change?

Comment: i figured it out, the [x] is supposed to be inside the parrentheses after the *, I will post an update

Comment: @Dog Interesting, the parentheses are for clarity, it should work without them too, thank you :)